# Division ring iff no proper left ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

An oft-quoted result (e.g., Hungerford #7a, p. 133)  is that a ring $R$ with identity is a division ring if and only if it has no proper left ideals.  Does this require the assumption $1_R\ne 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but if $1_R=0$, then $R$ is the zero ring. Then $R$ would trivially be devoid of proper ideals.

Comment: I think the question is "division rings are non-trivial. Does this criterion exclude the zero ring?".

Comment: So the question is "is the zero ring a division ring?"

Comment: No misunderstanding.  You're answering my question with a "yes."  So the usual statement is false without the assumption $1_R\ne0$.  In particular, the set of nonzero elements is empty, hence can't be a group under multiplication.  Thanks.

Comment: Hungerford's definition of a division ring specifically requires $1_R\ne0$.